# Error al exportar base de datos

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenas estoy intentando de exportar mi base de datos en MySQL para así luego vincularla al phpmyadmin del usuario con el que hosteo el proyecto. Lo que pasa es que al exportar mi base de datos, me salta un error y dice que fracaso.

El error que aparece es el siguiente:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT COLUMN_NAME,                       JSON_EXTRACT(HISTOGRAM, '$."number-of-buckets-specified"')                FROM information_schema.COLUMN_STATISTICS                WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'axis' AND TABLE_NAME = 'categories';': Unknown table 'column_statistics' in information_schema (1109)
```

No entiendo porque salta ese error, si alguien tiene la solución y como proceder para solucionarlo se los agradecería.

Comment: pareciera que el usuario que estas usando no tiene permisos para ejecutar esa consulta en la exportación; incluso pareciera que se esta exportando la tabla de configuracion de phpmyadmin o mysql ... tambien pareciera que el archivo dump que se uso no esta completo ya que el error indica que `column_statistics` no existe...

Comment: has probado que la exportacion e importacion de archivos esta funcionando correctamente o es primera vez que lo haces??

Comment: me parece que esta pregunta estaría mejor ubicada en: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso es la primera vez que lo hago, jamas importe nada solo obtuve la base de datos mediante migraciones de Laravel. El tema es que estoy retomando un proyecto de alguien que estaba en mi puesto de trabajo antes que mi.

Comment: suele pasar pero no es un problema de programacion

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta el resultado de `SHOW variables like '%stats_%'`